# Can't change size and color of svg file using IonIcon

Tags: ionic-framework, svg

I have a local svg files I downloaded from ionicons website.
I'm trying to change their font size and color, but nothing works.
I tried with `img` tag and change in the css file, didn't work.
I tried with IonIcon, which also does not work.

This is what I have right now:

```
const AppHeader = () => {
return (
    <div className="header">
        <div className="iconsContainer">
            <IonIcon src={searchIcon} size="36px" color="white"></IonIcon>
            <IonIcon src={cartIcon} size="36px" color="white"></IonIcon>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};
```

I also couldn't find anything about IonIcon in Ionic's website and IonIcon's go to definition in VSCode does not work for some reason.
The svg does display, but I can't change the size and color.

Comment: Which package you are using for IonIcon. I use ion icon and giving styles with fontSize and colors always chnage the size and color.

Comment: @moshfiqrony I just downloaded the icons from the website. I'm not using any package for this.

Comment: From which package this ```IonIcon``` component is imported?

Comment: try using a `fill` in css like `fill:red`

Comment: @moshfiqrony It does not seem to be imported from any library (I guess this is the basic Ionic React library)

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks, I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you give the whole file code please

Comment: @moshfiqrony I just started, this is the whole code. I doubled check, and IonIcon is coming from ```@ionic/react```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
<IonIcon icon={searchIcon} style={{fontSize:32, color: 'white'}}/>
```

Comment: Edited the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import IonIcon like that:-

```
import { IonIcon } from "@ionic/react";
```

If you are trying to use ionic icons you need to import the name as well:-

`import { search } from "ionicons/icons";`

Example with SVG/Images

```
<IonIcon src="/assets/icons/searchIcon"/>
```

Example with ionic icons

```
<IonIcon icon={search} style={{fontSize:36, color: 'white'}} />
```